# Numpy equivalent of if/elif/else that keeps the last value if the condition is not met

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, vectorization

I have the following code where variables "**close**", "**closeLow**" and "**closeHigh**" are Numpy 1D arrays of the same size.

I want to compute the array "**showData**", as shown in the code below, using some function as "np.where" or any other vectorized/efficient way.

```
showData = np.full(len(close), True)
for i in range(len(close)):
    if close[i] < closeLow[i]:
        showData[i] = True
    elif close[i] > closeHigh[i]:
        showData[i] = False
    else:
        showData[i] = showData[i-1]
```

The problem here is that I cannot find any simple way to reproduce the effect of the last line, where we keep the result of the last iteration if the 2 conditions (*if* and *elif*) are not met.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.select` and `pd.Series.ffill` to forward fill data.

```
showdata = pd.Series(np.select(
        [close < closeLow, close > closeHigh], [1., 0.], default=np.nan)
    ).ffill().astype(bool)
```

Works by assigning 1 or 0 where the condition is met accordingly, or NaN otherwise. `ffill` then just forward fills the NaNs with the last non-null value.

NaNs at the start of the array/series cannot be filled this way.